# Tkinter label widget showing variable two times

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am trying to create a corona tracker using a entry widget except everytime i try to search two times the search result shows two times. [Here](https://prnt.sc/sdj5rj) is the picture.

I have tried deleting the variable when the button widget but it didnt work.

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter

db = sqlite3.connect ('covidjakartadb.db')

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("500x300")
window.title("Corona tracker")

label = tkinter.Label(window, text="Please enter a area")
label.pack()

entry = tkinter.Entry(window)
entry.pack()

def Search_Completed():
    # select_all = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE '%{0}%'".format(entry)
    select_all = "SELECT positive FROM locations WHERE City LIKE '%{0}%'".format( entry.get() )
    cursor = sqlite3.Cursor(db)
    cursor.execute(select_all)
    positive = cursor.fetchall()
    print (positive)
    tkinter.Label (window, text=positive, font='Ariel 25 bold').pack()
    tkinter.Label (window, text="Tips to fight off the coronavirus")


Button = tkinter.Button(window, text="Search data", command=Search_Completed)
Button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Create the `Label` ahead of time, and only change its text inside the function.

Comment: Can i get some clarification? some code would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter

db = sqlite3.connect ('covidjakartadb.db')

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("500x300")
window.title("Corona tracker")

label = tkinter.Label(window, text="Please enter a area")
label.pack()

entry = tkinter.Entry(window)
entry.pack()

def Search_Completed():
     result["text"] = ""
    # select_all = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE '%{0}%'".format(entry)
    select_all = "SELECT positive FROM locations WHERE City LIKE '%{0}%'".format( entry.get() )
    cursor = sqlite3.Cursor(db)
    cursor.execute(select_all)
    positive = cursor.fetchall()
    print (positive)
    result["text"] = positive

Button = tkinter.Button(window, text="Search data", command=Search_Completed)
Button.pack()
result= tkinter.Label (window, text=positive, font='Ariel 25 bold')
result.pack()

window.mainloop()
```